# conflict in using getFragmentManager Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-support-library, android-dialogfragment

MainActivity is defined for sdk from 11 to 19, has 2 library, google-play-services and appcompat_v7, the last one has the android-support-v4.jar, my project has not, I've deleted its one because of SHA conflict. Everything went ok until I decided to add a fragment dialog. First, I've create a java file with a class defined below

```
package com.mypack;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class MyAlertDialogWIndow extends DialogFragment{
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.hello_world)
           .setItems(R.array.colors_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
  }
}
```

In the main activity it's desired that a button show the dialog when pressed so,

```
public void launch_service_colors(View view){
    //do some other stuff
      FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
      MyAlertDialogWIndow alert = new MyAlertDialogWIndow();
      alert.show(fm, "Alert_Dialog");
}
```

and Eclipse editor complains about getFragmentManager(), it says **Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager**, ok so I've tried to change it by getSupportFragmentManager() and editor now says **The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity**. I don't know what more to do :-(

Comment: Inherit your Activity from FragmentActivity to get getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: But why aren't you using `android.app.DialogFragment` instead of support library?

Answer (score 0):

Make `MainActivity` extend `FragmentActivity` from the support library.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   ...

   FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

   ...
}
```

Or if you are not using the support library, then don't use the `DialogFragment` provided by the library, use `android.app.DialogFragment`

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;

public class MyAlertDialogWIndow extends DialogFragment {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have already an extension, *public class MainActivity extends Activity {...* but if I change by your suggestion, a lot of errors came up

Comment: Are you using the support library? Either you use it or not. If you are not using it, then don't use DialogFragment from the support library

Comment: I've already it, the Android Support Library, it is downloaded in Extras at the SDK Manager

Comment: I changed code according to your last suggestion plus this line in the MainActivity *FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager()* by this  *android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager()*, now the app is OK. I wonder if my app continues being applicable for devices with Android 3.0, is it ?